# Achieve iphone 4 layout in iphone 5 using autolayout

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, autolayout

Since, AutoLayout enables to define dynamic GUIs.In iphone-4, the screen appears as:[image: 320x480.png]
For the boxes 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 ,5 and 6 their CGRect should satisfy the  'x/2' and 'y/2' constraints in all the iphone and ipad as shown.

Is this feasible to achieve it by only specifying constraints available in xib?
If yes, please enlighten our thought :)

Comment: it may be a typo: `y/3` instead...?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. Make sure each view has an equal width and equal height constraint to all the others (you can refer them all back to a single view for simplicity).

Then, pin them either to the superview edges or the edges of each other, as appropriate.

Using VFL to express the constraints, you want something like:

```
H:|[one][two(==one)]|
H:|[three(==one)][four(==one)]|
H:|[five(==one)][six(==one)]|

V:|[one][three(==one)][five(==one)]|
V:|[two(==one)][four(==one)][six(==one)]|
```

You can add all of these constraints in interface builder using the pinning menus.

If you're not familiar with VFL, the first line means:

- `H:` on the horizontal axis
- `|`: superview's leading edge
- `[one]`... pin leading edge of one to superview
- `[two(==one)]` ... pin leading edge of two to trailing edge of one, and make it the same width
- `|` ... Pin trailing edge of two to trailing edge of superview.

Comment: Damn, got there before me again :D

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? I've written about the pinning menus and adding constraints here, if that helps: http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2014/03/10/autolayout-in-interface-builder-xcode-5-dot-1/

Comment: can you please Describe V:|[one][three(==one)][five(==one)]| and V:|[two(==one)][four(==one)][six(==one)]|..thanku

Comment: Added some explanation.